# I can not exclude folder from rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess-configuration

I'm running a Joomla 3.3.6 site and I'm using rewrite. I have a subfolder, that doesn't belong to the joomla site.
I want to exclude this folder from the rewrite rule. This folder is also protected by a httaccess-file, but I cannot access it, because I always get a 404 error-page.

This is my htaccess:

```
## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(subfolder)$

#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks
Barbara

Comment: Like johanpw said the .htaccess checks if the folder exists. Is the folder password protected? That makes the folder check fail and Joomla show 404 error, if the server has a custom 401 error page defined.

Answer (score 1):

Could you put a .htaccess file containing:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

In the folders you want to exclude from being rewritten.

Comment: I've tried that already, but it didn't work

Comment: Could this work:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848500/htaccess-mod-rewrite-how-to-exclude-directory-from-rewrite-rule

Comment: RewriteRule ^(subfolder)($|/) - [L] - and place before the rewrite rules

Comment: Nothing of the above works :(

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you shouldn't have to exclude sub-folders inside your Joomla installation like that. It doesn't matter if the folder is part of Joomla or not.

The line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` in the default `.htaccess` file checks if the request matches an existing folder. If it does, the URL is not rewritten.

The problem might be something else, but probably related to your `.htaccess` file. Your question doesn't make it clear if you get a 404 error for *all* pages (both Joomla and your subfolder), or only when you try to visit the subfolder (e.g. http://example.com/subfolder).

Here's a couple of things you could check:

1. Comment/uncomment the line `# RewriteBase /` by adding/removing the initial `#` (depending on current state). If your Joomla installation is located within a subfolder of your domain (e.g. the url to your site is http://example.com/joomla), then change it to `RewriteBase /joomla`
2. Make sure no menu item in Joomla has the same alias as your subfolder. Joomla won't let you create an alias that matches an existing folder, but if you created the folder **after** creating the menu item there might be a conflict.
3. Make sure the `.htaccess` file in your subfolder is valid. If possible, rename it to anything you want and try visiting the subfolder again.
4. Make sure the **Joomla** `.htaccess` file is valid. If possible, rename it and try again, or try with a new `.htaccess` file from a clean Joomla installation.